# PostgreSQL: How to change the age Format in the output

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I have a **patient_age column** in **patient table** and the format of the age in that column will be like this,

```
10D8M45Y
```

(It means **10** **D**ays **8** **M**onths **45** **Y**ears)

I need a Postgresql Query which can give the output like this,

```
45 Years 8 Months 10 Days
```

Thank You.

Comment: varchar (character varying(10))

Comment: Doesn't Postgresql have any interval data type?

Comment: You shouldn't store ages in a database.  You should store dates of birth.  After all, the value will not be accurate tomorrow.

Comment: There is a Interval data type in Postgresql

Comment: Yeah you are right @Gordon Linoff, We store in both the ways. But when the User is not sure about the person DOB We added a feature of entering the Approximate age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format of the age in that column like this 'YY "Years" mm "Months" DD "Days".

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(age(current_date, '2017-04-17 00:00:00.0'), 'YY "Years" mm "Months" DD "Days"') as length_of_service
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you'd want to calculate age at the time of the query (if possible) like this...

```
SELECT extract(year from AGE(end_date, NOW()))||' Years '||
    extract(month from AGE(end_date, NOW()))||' Months '||
    extract(day from AGE(end_date, NOW()))||' Days '||
    extract(hour from AGE(end_date, NOW()))||' Hours '||
    extract(minute from AGE(end_date, NOW()))||' Minutes' as formatted_age
FROM my_table
```

It might be the case that you're dealing with something that got hard coded into a field.

```
SELECT
    extract(DAY FROM INTERVAL '10D8M45Y') || ' days ' ||
    extract(MONTH FROM CAST(REPLACE('10D8M45Y', 'M', 'Mon') AS INTERVAL)) || ' months ' ||
    extract(YEAR FROM INTERVAL '10D8M45Y') || ' years ';
```